# Center vertically the text of several cells with the array package

Tags: tables, arrays

I apologize if this problem has a functional solution that I have not found. I've looked at a lot of different solutions but I haven't been able to adapt them.

I would like to center vertically the text of each length measurement on this table because the first column contains text on two lines. I would like the measurements in centimeters not to be at the top of the cell, nor at the bottom, but centered vertically.

How can I do this?

[image: my tables]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\renewcommand {\arraystretch }{1.5}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{#1}<{$}}

\begin{tabular}{|p{16mm}|*{3}{M{1.2cm}|}}
\hline
longueur initiale & \SI{3}{cm} & \SI{4}{cm} & \SI{5}{cm}\\
\hline
longueur réduite &       & \SI{3.2}{cm} & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|p{16mm}|*{3}{w{c}{12mm}|}}
\hline
longueur initiale & \SI{3}{cm} & \SI{4}{cm} & \SI{5}{cm}\\
\hline
longueur agrandie &          & \SI{4.8}{cm} &               \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use m-type also in the first column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\renewcommand {\arraystretch }{1.5}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{#1}<{$}}

\begin{tabular}{|m{16mm}|*{3}{M{1.2cm}|}}
\hline
longueur initiale & \SI{3}{cm} & \SI{4}{cm} & \SI{5}{cm}\\
\hline
longueur réduite &       & \SI{3.2}{cm} & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|m{16mm}|*{3}{w{c}{12mm}|}}
\hline
longueur initiale & \SI{3}{cm} & \SI{4}{cm} & \SI{5}{cm}\\
\hline
longueur agrandie &          & \SI{4.8}{cm} &               \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Can you explain why it is necessary to use the same `m{}` specifier in each column? I didn't find an explanation for this in the manual (I certainly looked for it wrong).